# image scale with jquery and pagination

Tags: jquery, css, image

I am using the plugin imgscale.jquery.js to resize and fill the div with an image. This is working fine without the use of pager script. All images get resized and fills the div completly.

When using pagination however some pictures don't fill the whole space. Looks like not the whole script gets executed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('img.thumbnails').imgscale({ 
    parent : '.thumbnail_container',
fade : 3000 
    });   
  });
</script>
```

Would the it be possible to make sure that all images get processed for all pages?

Comment: Is pagination done via server-side or client-side (JS)?

Comment: Are you adding some of the pictures to the parent '.thumbnail_container' dynamically after dom-load?

Comment: Hi, pagination is done with jquery.pajinate.js from: http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/

Comment: No pictures are added this is the html part: {foreach item=item key=key from=$list2}
 <div class="thumbnail_container">
     <img src="getsnap.php?id={$item.ref_userid}" class="thumbnails" alt="" />
    </div>
{/foreach}